# Diablo 3 Wizard sparkflint familiar rune + conflagration?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

Does [sparkflint familiar](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/familiar) benefit from [conflagration](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/passive/conflagration) passive skill? I know that sparkflint does not benefit from temporal flux skill as un-runed familiar and cannoneer familiar do.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does.

Conflagration is a Wizard passive skill, which causes fire damage to set enemies ablaze, increasing their damage taken for a short period of time.

And Temporal Flux is a Wizard passive skill, which adds a slowing effect to enemies the Wizard hits for Arcane spell damage.

*Tooltips:*

### Conflagration

Fire damage dealt to enemies applies a burning effect,
increasing **all damage** done to them by 10% for 3 seconds.

### Temporal Flux

Whenever **you** deal Arcane damage, enemies are slowed by 30% for 2 seconds.

*Source:* 
http://www.diablowiki.com/Conflagration 
http://www.diablowiki.com/Temporal_Flux

Comment: The question is "Does the Sparkflint familiar deal fire damage, despite it not being listed on the tooltip", not about the passives themselves.

Comment: I do not believe sparkflint to show any type of damage increase with conflagration. Therefore I do not believe it is considered fire damage. :(

Comment: Thats not the question, and he does benefit from it.